# How reordering of instructions can cause concurrency issue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was reading about JMM (Java Memory Model) and I could understand that how flushing of the cache variables can cause other threads to have dirty reads. It was also mentioned that re-ordering of instructions can cause concurrency issues, even though I understood what is meant by re-ordering of the instructions I wouldn't understand how it can cause concurrency issues.

For example, suppose thread t1 has acquired lock while starting `test1()`, now even if compiler has done some optimization and there is some re-ordering because of which `z = 4;` has gone either up or down, now since t2 wouldn't get the lock for `test2()` until there t1 has released, so how re-ordering in `test1()` (and even in `test2()`) could cause concurrency issues/bugs?

```
public class Testing {
    private int z = 2;

    public synchronized void test1(){
        //some statement..
        z = 4;
        //some statement..
    }

    public synchronized void test2(){
        //some statement..
        System.out.println(z);
        //some statement..
    }
}
```

---

I understood that after proper synchronization re-ordering wouldn't cause the problem, but without synchronization even if compiler doesn't optimize and re-order still there are chances of concurrency issues, right? To be clear I was referring [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/) link, I couldn't understand their point about concurrency issues after re-ordering, because like I said if there is no synchronization then concurrency issues can still arise even without any re-ordering.

**EDIT:** Please discard my code snippet because after looking at comments it doesn't hold good now, and my updated question is as above.

Comment: Reordering isn't a problem when your code is correctly synchronized.

Comment: "could cause concurrency" Do you mean concurrency *bugs*?

Comment: @AndyTurner No, he means concurrency *issues*.

Comment: Reordering is one several types of optimization that can cause concurrency issues.

Comment: Yes, I got that point but in case of "reordering" I am not able to understand how it can use, and my reasons I have explained in my question.

Comment: what do you mean under "concurrency issues"? what issues you mean exactly? it is class of errors, not single type, like NPE

Comment: Note that reordering can also happen on the CPU, independent of the language or compiler used.

Comment: @1000ml That's true, and JVM takes care of that to ensure that if synchronized is used then there are no concurrency issues.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. Your snippet doesn't really demonstrate anything because it uses synchronization (and doesn't do much altogether).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't see the problem of reordering with a single variable. But take two and ...

```
int foo = 0;
boolean isFooSet = false;
...
// thread 1
foo = 42;
isFooSet = true;
...
// thread 2
while (!isFooSet) {/*waste some time*/} // we wait until the flag is set in the other thread
System.out.println(42/foo); //we can actually divide by zero here
```

So while thread 1 sees `foo` set before `isFooSet`, thread 2 can see them the other way around, which makes the flag `isFooSet` useless.

Note that without reordering this code would be perfectly safe (from dividing by zero, that is), as you can see if for example `isFooSet` is declared as `volatile`, preventing moving the write to `foo` **after** the write to `isFooSet`. *It also solves the other, non-reordering related problem of visibility, but that's a different story*

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer. But how it is related to reordering done by compiler/jvm as part of optimization, this is a general concurrecy issue, my question is about how there would be a concurrency issue because of re-ordering done by compiler/jvm as part of optimization.

Comment: @pjj I've rejigged the example a bit to demonstrate that reordering is the problem here, not concurrency in general.

Answer (score 1):

When reordering the JVM takes into account the happens-before relationships and does not make any reorderings that would be invalid for those relationships. Reorderings are a concern when you have a data race, see the book [Java Concurrency in Practice, 16.1.3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

> A data race occurs when a variable is read by more than one thread, but the reads and writes are not ordered by happens-before. A correctly synchronized program is one with no data races; correctly synchronized programs exhibit sequential consistency, meaning that all actions within the program appear to happen in a fixed, global order.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer. "JCIP"? You want to put some link?

Comment: @pij Nathan Hughes refers to book [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601).

Comment: @pjj: yes. Added link. Jcip is a common abbreviation you'll see on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to read the link that is pages and pages so please forgive me.  But I think I understand the gist of your question. And I do remember that this link is chapter 2 or 3 of JCIP.

EDIT 1: Answering the second question: "no concurrency, no reordering":

One more thing I would like to add (to the excellent set of answers here) is that you are assigning to an int so any assignment is atomic. Now imagine if it is a double or an object assignment. Without proper concurrency (and if there are no ordering as you take as a prerequisite) there are issues of "that object not being constructed properly" in test1 and used in test2.

For example:

```
SomeObject z = new SomeObject(yyy);

public void test1() {
    z = new SomeObject(xxx);
}

public void test2() {
   System.out.print(z);
}
```

Therefore my recommendation is to read the first 3 chapters of JCIP to get an idea of the Java Memory Model and these concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer.